# How to configure Yii Framework to use HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, yii, ssl-certificate

I just bought a `SSL certificate` for my website [linkbook.co](http://www.linkbook.co/);

My website is developed using the `Yii Framework`;

Do I have to configure the App to use `HTTPS` or will the server do this for me?

If I have to configure the App, how do I tell to the `widgets, clistviews, portlets`, etc, to use the HTTPS protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a good wiki article about it on the Yii website explaining [URL management for Websites with secure and nonsecure pages](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages)

The article is only usefull if you have some content that has to use HTTPS and some other HTTP. If you want everything going by HTTPS then it wont be usefull for you.

Comment: i dont really want the https all the time; my website is small; but, the bookmarklet, needs https, and my website will respons as https when requested by the bookmarklet;

Comment: i will; but this is a bigger problem, since a bookmarklet is involved; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090986/requests-of-a-bookmarklet-over-http-and-https

Answer (score 7):

You don't need configure yii app, just use in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: this should be easy; i have to wait fot the admins to install the ssl;

Comment: if I go https I get a blank page if I go http i get the website.  do we need to change the virtual host to listen on the other port?

Comment: This didn't work for me with a website on a subdomain.  For example, sub1.mysite.com.  I'm not on the www subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Add these instructions in your .htaccess which must be in the public_html folder where the index.php is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```