# I want to switch my website ( develop using YII ) from http to https, is there any coding change that i have to make?

Tags: php, http, yii, https

I have developed a website in yii framework and i want to switch my website from http to https , would it require any coding change or it automatically convert and open all the pages correctly?

Comment: If you've used `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` (instead of hard coding) for paths on your application then there shouldn't be any coding changes, just server configuration

Answer (score 0):

Apart from having to set up your server with a [valid certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Server_setup), you need to configure your web server application (Apache/Nginx) to use the certificate. After that, you need to make sure any anchors or hard-coded paths use the https protocol. Omitting `http(s):`in a uri (HTML) is a [nifty way to use the current protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http), be it http or https.

A fine explanation for Yii specifics can be found here: [How to configure Yii Framework to use HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083925/how-to-configure-yii-framework-to-use-https)